# Passing HTML 5 data attributes to Play! form inputs

Tags: java, forms, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm working with Java + Play 2.0.4 and I need to pass some "data-" attributes to my input fields like:

```
@inputDate(
  myform("start"),
  '_showConstraints -> false,
  '_label -> Messages("label.start.date"),
  'data-date-format -> "mm/dd/yyyy"
)
```

This throws "value - is not a member of Symbol" error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't remember where I saw this but it works:

```
Symbol("data-date-format") -> "mm/dd/yyyy"
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't going to guess this one in a long time :)

Comment: This has been fixed in Play 2.3. Checkout http://play-bootstrap3.herokuapp.com/docs#arguments-with-dashes for a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Check [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaFormHelpers) for creating own helpers

you cane use ie. way described in "Handling HTML input creation yourself" section, and if you plan to use it in many places you can also "write you own field constructor".

Comment: Yes, I just finished creating a helper for a bootstrap calendar field. I thought that maybe there was an easier way for this instead of rewritting all the already given helpers provided by the framework. I mean, it works for everything a throw at it that doesn't contain a dash.

Answer (score 0):

Well since @Ubersoldat said "it works for everything a throw at it that doesn't contain a dash." -> maybe that needs to be fixed in the Framework to make things easier?